# The primary nature of feeling

Tags: reference-request

Are there philosophical schools or traditions that support the idea, that the physical world is secondary (but neither illusion nor projection of own mind) and the feelings of people and their thoughts is the most important thing?

That one have direct influence upon our world, in the sense that they influence is not limited to the fact that one is part of social interactions.

Comment: After writing my answer, I do see a (slight) Platonic element to your question, so the time spent with Neoplatonism would not be wasted, should you choose to study it.

Comment: I mention this book, "Mastering Withchcraft" by Paul Huson, it is a book that properly links the accoutrements, and props of the occult with the Will. That is, the spells, the amulets, circles, pentagrams, etc.  are all used to "set", or fix the will to a certain purpose. To create the indomitable will. The only one of these type of books that a philosopher could take seriously imo. Please don't get the idea that I'm into this stuff.   The mundane world keeps me busy enough for me to ever fool around with it. There is a PDF, don't know if trustworthy.

Comment: This was the cover of the book when I read it:  https://www.biblio.com/book/mastering-witchcraft-practical-guide-witches-warlocks/d/1087810065?aid=frg&utm_source=google&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=feed-details&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI04SgwYjM2gIVgRGBCh0DGAkTEAQYAyABEgIZifD_BwE

Comment: Secondary, but not a projection. In what sense "secondary"? One has direct influence on the world, but it is still not a projection. What does that mean?  Does [social construction of reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism) count as influence or is it just part of social interactions? How about technological transformation of environment, or does it have to be something mystical/supernatural?

Comment: I was interested in indirect influence, because direct influence is very obvious for me. But it's not necessary should be strictly speaking mystical or supernatural, the most attractive idea that feelings is the foundation of nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely certain types of idealism, but with your last sentence you move into Schopenhauer, Nietzsche, even the pagan occult (West European variety); and Neoplatonism. In the so-called postmodern world, you are likely to get a jumble of the latter two, or even all of the above.

"The Will" is the key to the two named philosophers and the pagan occult, whereas with Neoplatonism it is a communication, a calling down, and a back and forth. (I don't consider the West Euro. pagan occult, itself, to be philosophy, but others may disagree).

Now, strictly speaking, Neoplatonism should not be lumped together with matters of The Will and West European occult,  but I include it because you will find Neoplatonist ideas mixed in with them in later books. What is Neoplatonism?

Neoplatonism, Biggs, Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/neoplatonism01bigggoog

[e.g. In the Roman Catholic Church, the saying is that a sacrament brings about what it signifies. E.g. The holy Eucharist is not merely a sign of grace, but it brings about more grace for those who receive it, and it does this each time they receive it. This has a very Augustinian-Neoplatonist feeling to me, rather than the usual Aristotle-Thomism.].

The key thing for you to keep in mind is that when you get into your last paragraph you will be in a world of jumble and frustration, especially with modern books. I will also put down E.R. Dodds:  https://classicalstudies.org/annual-meeting/146/abstract/irrational-and-paranormal-legacy-e-r-dodd  Dodds was a master classicist, but I can't speak for his paranormal ideas, I just don't know. Finally, back in the day, Duke Univ. did some scientific research on the paranormal.

I hope I have understood your question; it has been difficult for me to find an exact fit for you.

I will also leave you this on A.N. Whitehead, because I can see the possibility that it may interest you.   http://www.shaviro.com/Blog/?p=1309

P.S. Think of West European occult as being "from below", and Neoplatonism "from above". But with Neoplatonism there can be a kind of communication back and forth.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I will dig in your recommendations.

I can't edit the link in your answer, but I should notice, that the last symbol was lost:
https://classicalstudies.org/annual-meeting/146/abstract/irrational-and-paranormal-legacy-e-r-dodds

Comment: @beivereser  Thank you. Good luck in studying these subjects.  Perhaps you should look into Schelling and Hegel too, but these are huge projects. :)  Also, perhaps take a look at entries on SEP for panentheism and pantheism. Also, I thought Conifold's question about technology was a very good point.